# When writing a file to disk some characters in the filename change

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a little web scraper and saving the html to my local disk so that I don't have to keep poking a web server for data everytime I crash or want to change the program.

My problem occurs when I write filenames to the disk. Here's an example:

```
Astro Bot: Rescue Mission.html
```

becomes

```
Astro Bot/ Rescue Mission.html
```

It's turning the ':' character to '/'. Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Here's the code that writes the file:

```
def save_html_local(request_data,local_dir, local_filename):

if os.path.isdir(local_dir) is False:
    try:
        print("Local Dir exists! Saving " + local_filename + " to " + local_dir)
        os.mkdir(local_dir)
    except OSError:
        print("Directory creation failed for " + str(local_dir))
    else:
        print("Directory created for: " + str(local_dir))

html_file = open(local_dir + local_filename, "wb")
html_file.write(request_data)
html_file.close()
```

Comment: The file system does not allow `:` to be part of the filename and it is removing it. Not sure why it is adding the `/`, how are you looking at the list of files?. `\` is a path separator so it isn't allowed as part of a filename either. What OS are you using?

Comment: can you show this happening in a [mcve]? Is that a filename or contents? On an unrelated note, look into os.path.join instead of +, and use open as html_file

Comment: Old versions of MacOS used `:` as the directory separator, so it was translated to `/`. But I haven't seen that behavior in many years.

Comment: I am on MacOS 10.12.6, so that seems to explain it. I started just using replace() when creating the filenames.